# staining the lumber

Tags: deck, staining, stain

I have some old decking boards which I'm planning to sand and re-use for new deck. It it not pressure-treated wood, and it has never been stained or painted etc.

So I would like somehow to prevent the old lumber, will the staining be enough for it? There is many kinds of stain, as I understand for old wood is solid stain recommended. What is clear base stain?

Thanks.

Comment: The new deck will quickly become an old deck if you use untreated wood for the exposed top surface. I would "bite the bullet" as we say and invest in treated lumber or the newer plastic type woods for the deck.

Comment: Fair enough. However, for educational purposes, could you explain about clear base stain. What exactly this means? Thanks.